# Vue/Vuex: Distinguish arrays from objects in Proxy objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

As stated [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-array-converted-to-proxy-object/113650), reactive Vuex objects are returned as Proxy objects. This may not be a problem in most cases, but how do I determine if the Proxy originated from an array or object?

Comment: `Array.isArray` should still return true for an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Proxy` is a transparent layer on top of the array/object, so you would not need to determine the `Proxy`'s original source.

The variable itself should be treated as if the `Proxy` layer were not there. If it's a `Proxy` of an `Array`, treat the variable as an `Array`, and the same for `Object`. Run the following code snippet for examples.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3]
const arrProxy = new Proxy(arr, {})             // value is identical to `arr`
console.log(arrProxy.map(x => x * 10))          // => [ 10, 20, 30 ]
console.log('isArray', Array.isArray(arrProxy)) // => true

const obj = { foo: true, bar: false }
const objProxy = new Proxy(obj, {})            // value is identical to `obj`
console.log(Object.keys(objProxy))             // => [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
console.log('objArray type:', typeof objProxy) // => object
```